# Rearranging an equation involving partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, mathematical-modeling

I have the equation $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+cA^m\frac{\partial A}{\partial s}=0$. I need to rearrange so that the coefficient of the $\frac{\partial A}{\partial s}$ term is equal to 1.

Since the partial derivative term of interest is with respect to $s$, I figured that I could treat $cA^m$ as a constant with respect to $s$, leading to $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (cA^{m+1})}{\partial s}=0$. But the correct rearrangement is apparently $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \left(\frac{cA^{m+1}}{m+1}\right)}{\partial s}=0$. I am struggling to see why I have to divide $cA^{m+1}$ by $m+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even think that you can treat $cA^{m+1}$ as a constant with respect to $s$? Think of it like in ODEs -
$$\frac{\partial \left(\frac{cA^{m+1}}{m+1}\right)}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial \left(\frac{cA^{m+1}}{m+1}\right)}{\partial A}\frac{\partial A}{\partial s} = cA^m\frac{\partial A}{\partial s}$$

Comment: The reason I thought it could be treated as a constant was because, for instance, when rearranging something like $\frac{dX(x)T(t)}{dt}$ you can take out the X so that it becomes $X(x)\frac{dT(t)}{dt}$. Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now.